# Unable to get HDMI audio to work on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, hdmi

I am hoping that one of you exceptionally clever people will be able to help me with a problem that is about to drive me insane...

I have been trying absolutely everything in order to get HDMI audio working from my laptop through to my television (used as an extended monitor), but despite trying so many different things I cannot get it to work!  It started out as an interesting troubleshooting exercise, but after trashing the OS several times and having to do complete reinstalls too many times for comfort I have decided to seek the help of experts.

I have updated ALSA drivers, updated NVIDIA drivers, updated the kernel, installed many different packages and tried many different configurations but nothing I do seems to work.

I am using an ASUS N56VM with a [GeForce GT 630M](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-630M/specifications) GPU.  The soundcard is a [Realtek ALC663](http://www.realtek.com/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=37&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=165).

There are no options for HDMI in the sound settings, even when updating Alsa drivers and pulseaudio settings.  I have a feeling that it may be something to do with my Kernel config but I am too much of a novice to be able to work out how to make the required changes (if indeed this is what is wrong).

I would be MASSIVELY grateful to anyone who can assist me!  I am aware that you may require further information from me, so please let me know what it is and I will get it posted as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance!